# Did Bob Mulét's voice actor change?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've heard from various sources that the character of Bob Mulét has changed voice actors. However, I cannot find a source for the voice actor in any credits. I believe it to be [Tituss Burgess](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm4270695/?ref_=tt_cl_t2) from *The Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt* fame (he is listed as voicing The Local Population, but not specifically Bob Mulét).

Has this been verified or is there any source regarding the reason of changing voice actors?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but who was Bob Mulét again? I only remember Franklin, Michael, and Trevor.

Comment: @Nolonar the hairdresser, it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV/comments/320ebi/til_that_adam_west_voiced_a_guard_in_the_prologue/cq7h7r4/), it looks like others share the same sentiment that it is Tituss Burgess who voices Bob Mulét.

> Pretty sure Titus from Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt/D'Fwan from 30 Rock is the stylist at Bob Mulet.

[Another thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/KimmySchmidt/comments/35r2zi/i_think_i_just_found_tituss_in_gta_v/#bottom-comments) seems to be full of people who believe Bob Mulét to be voiced by Tituss Burgess, as well.

> User 1: Yeah i remember going to the barber in-game recently and thinking "Isn't that Titus?"
>
> User 2: That's awesome! His voice is so recognisable!

---

Note that none of this is confirmed officially, as Tituss Burgess is only listed as voicing "Local Population", as you've noted. It is unlikely that Rockstar will release who voices Bob Mulét at this point, since the game has been out for over 3 years now and they have not done so yet. However, since multiple fans have recognized his voice and he is a credited voice actor, I think it is a safe bet.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently yes the voice actor has changed however no reason ahs been specified for it. I recommend searching the internet and I have a thread that might help you understand the issue. ***http://gtaforums.com/topic/813312-why-have-they-changed-bob-mulets-voice/***